# View HTML file via gmail attachment

Tags: java, html, css, gmail, content-security-policy

When i send a HTML file as an attachment via gmail manually or through JAVA, I have to download the file in order to view the file in proper format and design.

If i click on the attachment to view my file, I am only able to view the text.

Is there a way to view HTML file in pretty format or in proper form with CSS directly via the attachment in the mail?

Comment: Kindly clear, you are using java for this or using gmail app?

Comment: @Coder1 I have tried it both way, used java to send a file and then manually attached the HTML file.